# How would I make this read all the names from my text file instead of just one?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
f = open('name.txt')

line = f.readline()

print line
names = line.split()
print names
first = names[0]
last = names[1]

print first
print last
print first[0].lower()
address = last[0].lower() + first[0].lower() + "@gmail.com"
print address
```

I'm a beginner at this and I'm honestly lost. How would I make this read all the names from the text file? I've only managed to get it to read one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop and *iterate* over the lines. Mind that you better use a `with` context if you work with files, and perhaps use `mode='r'` explicitly:

```
with open('name.txt',mode='r') as f:
    for line in f:

        print line
        names = line.split()
        print names
        first = names[0]
        last = names[1]

        print first
        print last
        print first[0].lower()
        address = last[0].lower() + first[0].lower() + "@gmail.com"
        print address
```

`for` will *loop* over every `line` in the file `f` and then perform the *body* of the `for` loop (here the code like `print line`, etc.).

Furthermore the `with` is used to ensure that the file is *properly closed* once the program exits the `with` context. Otherwise you will have to do it yourself with `f.close()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea you could use those words. Thank you again.

Comment: It is worth to mentioning that using the "with open(...)" you do not need to close the file. Otherwise you would have to close it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
f = open('name.txt')

for row in f:

print line
names = line.split()
print names
first = names[0]
last = names[1]

print first
print last
print first[0].lower()
address = last[0].lower() + first[0].lower() + "@gmail.com"
print address
```

Comment: This program is not properly intended and thus will it fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('name.txt')
print( list(map(lambda one: one.split()[0]+ one.split()[1]+'@gmail' , file)))
```

in 2 lines, using map + lambda!